# Remove dead computer from Live Mesh

Tags: windows, windows-live, windows-live-mesh

I have Windows Live Mesh set up on a few machines I use frequently.  I previously had it set up on a work machine at a company I'm no longer at--but didn't think to uninstall it from that computer before I left.

That machine still shows in my "Remote" section of my Mesh client--how do I get rid of it, since that machine is truly gone?

Comment: I'm not sure Mesh offers the ability to delete a computer. They probably assume people would use the uninstall function and then remove the computer that way. However, I can complete understand there are times the computer dies before you can remove any items, which means their assumption is bad.

Comment: Yeah, it's a real problem--I have several machines in that "ghostly" state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you login to https://devices.live.com/, you will see the list of all devices in your Mesh. Simply choose "Manage" for the computer in question. Once on the detail, you can select "Stop using this service."

Comment: I'd give you +10 if I could.  Thank you, sir!  You've totally solved my only gripe with Mesh.

Comment: It is not as intuitive as it could be, I'll give you that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Mesh offers the ability to delete a computer. They probably assume people would use the uninstall function and then remove the computer that way. However, I can complete understand there are times the computer dies before you can remove any items, which means their assumption is bad.

In a search of their help section, forums, and the Live Mesh interface at devices.live.com, I did not find any tool or help regarding this question.

I would recommend you try posting a question in the [Live Mesh forum](http://windowslivehelp.com/product.aspx?productid=24&version=15.3.2804.0607) where a Live spokeperson (as opposed to a dead or even undead or possibly just not-live) may be able to provide either an answer or forward the request to the appropriate teams for resolution.